# How to be able to execute sql script if necessary using flyway?

Tags: maven, flyway

I have application running on many remote servers, i have set up flyway migration, but sometimes is need to manually execute script on several servers. It's any possibility to execute this script and store it in flyway history ?

Comment: To be honest, why would you like to keep this in flyway if you will need it `only sometimes`, not on every servers?

Comment: It's question from my client. They want to keep all history of executed scripts on every server. Next question is: Would be any error if i run script manually and in future flyway migration this script is not listed ?

Comment: Yeah, you're likely to see errors if you pull a script. It'll cause the check sum to fail and will look like drift or a failed deployment. If you had to do something like this, some kind of IF statement within the script and a tag or setting or something, in the database might be a way to optionally run some code. I haven't tested that, so I'm not sure it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an new enterprise feature in Flyway 7. You can do it with a combinations of [cherryPick](https://flywaydb.org/blog/flyway-7.0.0-beta#cherry-pick-migrations) (which lets you selectively run only certain migrations) and [mark as applied](https://flywaydb.org/blog/flyway-7.0.0-beta#mark-as-applied)(which lets you mark a migration as applied in the schema history, without running it manually).

See https://flywaydb.org/blog/flyway-7.0.0-beta#try-it-out for instructions on how to try it out.